# Struggling with contact form and image alignments

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment, contacts

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQAJT.png]

As you can see in the image, somehow the first sentence of the contact form weirdly starts somewhere near the top of the image, and the rest below it.

The image simply has a fixed width:200px and float:right; property.
The contact form is a simply contact form 7 in wordpress.

Any ideas on how I should be able to have the "Naam Kind*" also start below the image?

Comment: You should really provide some relevant code sample.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a float left for the image and then a break tag before "Naam Kind*"  or better still put the image in a paragraph and then the form in another paragraph. if it doesn't work, try uploading your css for the image and the form.